# How to put an if statement inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I want to change the value of `volgendecylinder` when I am at the last number of the loop.

I have tried the below code but this doesn't seems to work:

```
for (i = 1; i < aantalDwars; i++) { 

    var geometry2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( dwarsDiameter * scale , dwarsDiameter * scale , lengte2*scale , 20 );
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe4734f} );
    var cylinder2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
    cylinder2.userData.type = 'cylinder';

    scene.add( cylinder2 );
    if (i = aantalDwars){
        volgendeCylinder = ((lengte*scale)/2) + uitsteekLinks
    }

    cylinder2.position.set( ((lengte*scale)/2)+volgendeCylinder2, 1 , 0);
    volgendeCylinder2 -= (dwarsMaas*scale);
    cylinder2.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison

Comment: so what is a comparison in javascript? ==?

Comment: also loop is up to *i < aantalDwars* so it will never be equal to aantalDwars.

Comment: @EnzoMannaert `==` will check if two items are roughly the same (`"1" == 1 => true`), `===` will check if the two variables are identical

Comment: alright thanks nick! And AZ_ yeah I realised that also when I was re-reading it.

Comment: In the future, you may want to avoid using the phrase "it doesn't work" because it triggers a (fairly well-founded) reflex to request more details and/or flag your question as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Okay i will do that :)

Comment: so many downvotes, why? Sorry that I never worked in javascript before.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (i = 1; i < aantalDwars; i++) { 

    var geometry2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( dwarsDiameter * scale , dwarsDiameter * scale , lengte2*scale , 20 );
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xe4734f} );
    var cylinder2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
    cylinder2.userData.type = 'cylinder';

    scene.add( cylinder2 );
    if (i == aantalDwars-1){
    volgendeCylinder = ((lengte*scale)/2) + uitsteekLinks

    }

    cylinder2.position.set( ((lengte*scale)/2)+volgendeCylinder2, 1 , 0);
    volgendeCylinder2 -= (dwarsMaas*scale);
    cylinder2.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
}
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain what you did

Comment: just only changed the if statement 
if (i == aantalDwars-1)
in this lie only made changes

Comment: Please flag typo questions for closure - they're explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow. Answering is not appropriate